# Device names for internal\external HDDs when installing on external USB HDD

Tags: grub2, external-hdd

Really sorry to bump in with a silly question, please bear with a newbie.

I want to install Ubuntu on an external USB HDD attached to a pre-UEFI BIOS PC with 3 internal HDD/SSDs. The installation procedure looks transparent enough, I can partition and mount etc. no problem.

What bothers me is the installation DVD identifies my external USB HDD as /dev/sdb (/dev/sda being Windows system disk, /dev/sdc - my main Program Files disk) . But I don't know (yet) if this assignment would be permanent, that is if I plug my external HDD in tomorrow , would it still be /dev/sdb ? I read that sometimes those names can be re-assigned by the system, and I'm worried that in that case I won't be able to boot anymore, although I'm planning to install GRUB onto /dev/sdb, too.

Alternatively, I can unplug all my internal drives and then -- I presume -- the installation DVD would recognise my external HDD as /dev/sda. But -- when I re-attach internal disks after installing Ubuntu, would the name for the external HDD still be /dev/sda ?

I also read something about persistent naming through UUID, labels ets but -- again -- I'm not sure if GRUB will work with that.

The main aim of the whole ordeal is to let the two systems run unawares of each other. What would be the best installation strategy ?

Any suggestion would make me one happy man as I'm about to start knocking my head on a nearest wall.

Thanks a lot !